# NodeJS - Get certificate Chain from P7B file

Tags: node.js, cryptography, pkcs#7, ecdsa, p7b

I'm trying to take a CMS base64 encoded string, convert it into a pkcs7 file and extract the leaf and intermediate certificates using javascript/nodejs, similar to the following openssl command:

```
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in certificate.p7b -out certificate.cer
```

I've read almost every article and see solutions in other languages, but not for node. I understand you can achieve what I need using node-forge, but node-forge does not support ECC algorithms. Anyone know of any other solutions/npm packages that can help me accomplish this? Please help me. I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see [PKI.js](https://pkijs.org/) for Node.js? It is a pure JavaScript library implementing the formats that are used in PKI applications. It is based on the [W3C Web Cryptography API](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/) with full support for all "Suite B" algorithms in CMS messages. Code snippet submitted by OP:

```
const cmsSignedBuffer = stringToArrayBuffer(fromBase64(token.signature)); 
const asn1 = asn1js.fromBER(cmsSignedBuffer); 
const cmsContentSimpl = new pkijs.ContentInfo({ schema: asn1.result }); 
const cmsSignedSimpl = new pkijs.SignedData({ schema: cmsContentSimpl.content })
```

Another approach is to use a wrapper for openssl like [openssl-nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openssl-nodejs), for example.  The wrapper simply spawns a child process to invoke openssl. Thus, openssl must be installed on system where the Node.js application is deployed.

Comment: Thank you so much, PKI.js did exactly what I'm looking for. For anyone else that comes across this issue I simply did 
`const cmsSignedBuffer = stringToArrayBuffer(fromBase64(token.signature));
    const asn1 = asn1js.fromBER(cmsSignedBuffer);
    const cmsContentSimpl = new pkijs.ContentInfo({ schema: asn1.result });
 const cmsSignedSimpl = new pkijs.SignedData({ schema: cmsContentSimpl.content });` 
Then cmsSignedSimpl contained the certificates I was looking for.

Comment: Excellent. I've added your snippet to the answer text. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: I'm trying to read a p7b file to extract the issuer information but I can't get it. Could you give a full example?